# Selecting non-nested subnodes with JQuery

Tags: jquery, tree-traversal

I have a HTML structure that contains nested divs with the `container` class:

```
<div class="container" id="0">
  <div id="1">
    <div class="container" id="2">
      <div class="container" id="3"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="4">
      <div class="container" id="5"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This could include more divs and deeper/different nesting.

Starting from some point in the tree I'd like to find all containers in that subtree that are not nested within other containers. So for example from div `#1` I'd like to find the divs `#2` and `#5`, but not `#3` (since it is nested in container `#2` already found).

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Numeric IDs are invalid. That said, is there a reason why you wouldn't just select them by their ID? Or do they not actually have IDs?

Comment: @patrick: I only put the ids there to make it easier to talk about the different divs, they are not actually there in the real code.

Comment: I see. Will the ones you want to exclude always be a *direct* child of another `.container`? Or could there be some non `.container` separating them?

Comment: Also, since you don't have IDs, how are you selecting `#1`? Or should its selection be part of the solution? It makes a bit of a difference if using a selector-based solution.

Comment: @patrick: In general the ones I want to exclude are **not** necessarily a direct child of another `container`. There could be other nodes separating them. The "base node" `#1` would already be selected by other means, for example by a global id or by some previous selection done in the outer `#0` container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution working with arbitrary starting nodes:

```
function getContainers(base) {
   return base.find('.container').not(base.find('.container .container'));
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/tejp/GSRH2/2/

The advantage is that this works with an arbitrary starting node that doesn't need to be selectable with a simple JQuery selector, like it is the case in some of the other answers. Also it doesn't require "manually" walking over the whole tree with `children()`.

The approach can also be easily extended to similar problems, like for example getting all `.item`s not nested into a `.container`.

Answer (score 2):

Try using jQuery's [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method:

```
$items = $('#0').find('.container').filter(function(index) {
    return !$(this).parents(':not(#0)').hasClass('container');
});
```

Basically, it finds all items with class `.container` below your top `.container` and filters the set based on whether or not the direct parent has the class `.container`.

See here for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/TzL8Z/1

Comment: although that doesnt work if the nesting isnt 1 level down, e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/r8nED/ all i changed was i made id=3 1 level further down in the markup. the OP said he doesn't want id=3 selected, but your algorithm selects it - you need to use `parents()` not `parent()` which should make my solution faster

Comment: @davin: Thanks for the heads up, though your solution isn't entirely correct either. You need to use `parents(':not(#0)')` or else it returns no set because the outer container has the class `container`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: i dont see where my solution returns no set when the expected output is not empty.. now that you use `parents()` your solution doesnt solve the original problem because you're looking up the tree too far: http://jsfiddle.net/TzL8Z/3/

Comment: i didnt intend on ambushing you. im not normally a prick, please dont take it personally.

Answer (score 2):

```
function getOuterContainers(el) {

    if (el.length == 0)
        return $([]);
    else
        return el.children('.container').add( getOuterContainers(el.children(':not(.container)')) );

}
```

check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/GZ3Tx/